# Ruby Shoes "file.rb:18: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting tASSOC"

Tags: ruby, syntax, shoes

I have searched for a solution but didn't understand the answers well enough to apply them to my application. Here's the code:

```
require "soundcloud"
require "open-url"
require 'taglib'

client = SoundCloud.new({
    :client_id     => 'MyClientID',
    :client_secret => 'MyCLientSecret',
    Shoes.app{
        para "Input username"
        @username = edit_line
        para "Input password"
        @password = edit_line
        @but = button "OK"
        @but.click({
            :username => @username.text,
            :password => @password.text
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: You have a glaring syntax error. You cannot drop executable code in the middle of a hash that way. You can use anything that evaluates to an expression as a key, or a value, but you can't just drop expressions into a hash.

Comment: thanks, I it was a foolish mistake.